# Update Postgresql to newer version breaks legacy code

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos, rpm

As Postgresql versions less than 9.5 are becoming unsupported I need to update this package in my Centos environment.

`Current version: postgres -V (PostgreSQL) 9.2.24`

Also in my ecosystem, there is another rpm that uses postgresql. For this rpm there are build, restart scripts and also various scripts that monitor dependency services, check status etc.

These scripts all reference postgresql using kwywork `postgresql`

https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/ provided the exact steps how to do update/install. However for 9.6 version for example one need to use `postgresql-9.6` keywords to refer to postgresql

This means one will need to go through all references of postgresql in scripts and code and analyze if it needs to be changed. Updating to another version afterwards would of course mean repeating this process.

Is there any 'out of the box' approach that allows us to leave the scripts untouched for this update?

I'm also copy/pasting the install postgresql 9.6 steps here.

```
yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm

yum install postgresql96-devel postgresql96-server

/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb

systemctl enable postgresql-9.6

systemctl start postgresql-9.6
```

This is to check all is good

```
service postgresql-9.6 status
```

Comment: You hardly ever need the PostgreSQL version is a script. How can we answer this question without knowing your system or the scripts on it?

Comment: Well suppose you want to init the db . With previous version you did "service postgresql initdb" , now you need to "/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb"  This is problematic for existing scripts

Comment: Well the solution is not to have the version number in the script. Add everything that's version dependent in a single script and source that everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any "out of the box approach".

You should alyways read detailed [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/9.6.0/) to check if there is some incompatibility when upgrading.

Comment: I'm not concerned about Postgreql newer version introducing changes that my code does not handle. I'm unhappy about the fact that it was handled using postgresql and now  it is postgresql-version.  Therefore commands like "service postgresql status" need to become "service postgresql-<version> status"

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand: does this mean RPM name is hard-coded in the application ? If not what is really the issue ?

Comment: OK I got it. But I don't know any out-of-the box approach to take this into account.

Comment: @klausjohan this is probably a change made to allow for different versions of postgresql to be installed on the same machine. Debian made a similar change some years ago. It makes it much easier to upgrade an installatin because you can have e.g. 9.5 and 9.6 and dump/restore databases one at a time. If you only check your server setup once every five years then you are going to miss these sort of changes I'm afraid.

Comment: @Richard Huxton, you're spot on, ~5 years it's about right.